# How can user adjust html table column widths during session

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

How can user adjust html table column widths during their html session ?

The table *td* elements contain mostly text input fields that are sensibly sized via css classes and the table will default to accomodate them. This will probably result in some horizontal scrolling, but that is okay.

But during an editing session user may need to increase width of some columns to aid their editing, how do I do this it does't matter if these settings are lost next time they load the page.

I'm assuming I use Javascript to update the field width but how do I trigger this, what is the visual cue ?

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label>
                #
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="largeinputfield">
                Album
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Genre
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Album Artist
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Sort Album Artist
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Album Artists
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Sort Album Artists
            </label>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM" value="The Orchestral Suites" class="largeinputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13GENRE" value="" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTIST" value="Johann Sebastian Bach; Academy of Ancient Music, Christopher Hogwood" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTIST_SORT" value="Bach, Johann Sebastian; Academy of Ancient Music; Hogwood, Christopher" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTISTS" value="Johann Sebastian Bach;;;Academy of Ancient Music;;;Christopher Hogwood" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTISTS_SORT" value="Bach, Johann Sebastian;;;Academy of Ancient Music;;;Hogwood, Christopher" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
    1
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14ALBUM" value="The Orchestral Suites" class="largeinputfield" type="text">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14GENRE" value="" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14ALBUM_ARTIST" value="Johann Sebastian Bach; Academy of Ancient Music, Christopher Hogwood" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14ALBUM_ARTIST_SORT" value="Bach, Johann Sebastian; Academy of Ancient Music; Hogwood, Christopher" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14ALBUM_ARTISTS" value="Johann Sebastian Bach;;;Academy of Ancient Music;;;Christopher Hogwood" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14ALBUM_ARTISTS_SORT" value="Bach, Johann Sebastian;;;Academy of Ancient Music;;;Hogwood, Christopher" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this, where you can use javascript to add draggable areas (set to blue for visibility). If you mess around with this, you should get to the solution you're looking for.

The set width on the table is important, as it won't work properly without that.

This goes through and automatically appends a resizing trigger to each TH element. Mousedown on that element sets its parent TH to the active element, which allows the global mousemove event to change its size.

```js
function each(arr, fn){
  let i = arr.length
  while(--i > -1){ fn(arr[i]) }
}

function px(val){ return [val, 'px'].join("") }

var resizeElement, startSize, startX

function beginResize(e){
  killResize()
  let th = e.target.parentElement
  resizeElement = th
  startSize = th.clientWidth
  startX = e.pageX
}

function killResize(){
  resizeElement = null
  startSize = null
  startX = null
}

each(document.querySelectorAll('th'), elem => {
  let trigger = document.createElement('span')
  trigger.className = 'resizeTrigger'
  
  trigger.addEventListener('mousedown', beginResize)
  
  elem.appendChild(trigger)
})

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if(resizeElement){
    let diff = e.pageX - startX
    resizeElement.style.width = px(startSize + diff)
  }
})

document.addEventListener('mouseup', killResize)
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  position: relative;
}

th > .resizeTrigger {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  right: -4px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
input {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label>
                #
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="largeinputfield">
                Album
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Genre
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Album Artist
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Sort Album Artist
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Album Artists
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Sort Album Artists
            </label>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM" value="The Orchestral Suites" class="largeinputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13GENRE" value="" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTIST" value="Johann Sebastian Bach; Academy of Ancient Music, Christopher Hogwood" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTIST_SORT" value="Bach, Johann Sebastian; Academy of Ancient Music; Hogwood, Christopher" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTISTS" value="Johann Sebastian Bach;;;Academy of Ancient Music;;;Christopher Hogwood" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTISTS_SORT" value="Bach, Johann Sebastian;;;Academy of Ancient Music;;;Hogwood, Christopher" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thankyou but it seems to have a problem, it adjusts the width of the table column but not the input field within it therefore not helping the user, can input field be set to width of table column or something

Comment: Oh, yeah just give the inputs `width: 100%`, updated

Comment: much better solution. You could even extend the blue drag areas all the way down.

Comment: @jmcgriz thanks looks good, but if I input field width to 100% does that mean I cant default to my chosen sizes (mediuminputfield, largeimnputfield etc)

Comment: Oh Ithink I have it, just used mediuminputfield etc on the th element

Comment: Great I have it working, a couple of points 1> I didn't need the css on the table table {table-layout: fixed;width: 100%;} to make it work. 2> @jmcgriz Probably need to add some help so users realize they can resize. 3> This does rely on mouse, so would need to add something to allow it to work on a tablet

Comment: @jmcgriz Just realized another issue it doesnt let you resize columns no wider than screen width, i.e if make one column wider its at expense of another if table is at screen width, tried wrapping table in div with <div style="overflow-x: auto"> and that shows scrollbar when at full width but doesnt allow me to make table wider ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor You'd have to set a width on the table itself. Tables are a bit finicky when it comes to sizing

Comment: But I dont have a width in mind, i.e if enough room to display fine, if the user wants to make table much larger then also fine.

Answer (score 2):

Convert all inputs to textareas, as there is no need to write a javascript solution. Apply correct css.
Textareas have a resize option. You may want to customize it with JavaScript.

For resizable columns there are numerous ways. I spent the time making a shoddy solution and would rather do it completely differently, but here is something to get you started...

It uses textareas instead of inputs. For each textarea in a column, resizing it will resize all textareas in that column to be the same width. Obviously the css needs tweaking as they don't perfectly align, so it's not a great solution.

A better solution would be to get the x position of each column divider, and be able to set these x positions as desired. But I will look into that another time.

```js
let allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let cols = document.querySelectorAll('table tr th').length-1;
let isDown = false;
let elSelected = null;
let allTextareas = Array.from(allInputs).map((el, i)=>{
  let newEl = document.createElement("textarea");
  newEl.innerHTML = el.value;
  newEl.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    isDown = true;
    elSelected = {el: this, i: i, colID: i%cols};
  });
  el.parentNode.appendChild(newEl);
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  return {el: newEl, colID: i%cols};
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
  isDown = false;
  elSelected = null;
});

let colWidth = 0;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
  if(isDown && elSelected){
    if(elSelected.el.clientWidth != colWidth){
      colWidth = elSelected.el.clientWidth;
      allTextareas.forEach((o, j)=>{
        if(elSelected.i !== j && elSelected.colID === o.colID){
          o.el.style.width = colWidth+'px';
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label>
                #
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="largeinputfield">
                Album
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Genre
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Album Artist
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Sort Album Artist
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Album Artists
            </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            <label class="mediuminputfield">
                Sort Album Artists
            </label>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM" value="The Orchestral Suites" class="largeinputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13GENRE" value="" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTIST" value="Johann Sebastian Bach; Academy of Ancient Music, Christopher Hogwood" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTIST_SORT" value="Bach, Johann Sebastian; Academy of Ancient Music; Hogwood, Christopher" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTISTS" value="Johann Sebastian Bach;;;Academy of Ancient Music;;;Christopher Hogwood" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="13ALBUM_ARTISTS_SORT" value="Bach, Johann Sebastian;;;Academy of Ancient Music;;;Hogwood, Christopher" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td class="tableheading ui-corner-all">
    1
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14ALBUM" value="The Orchestral Suites" class="largeinputfield" type="text">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14GENRE" value="" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14ALBUM_ARTIST" value="Johann Sebastian Bach; Academy of Ancient Music, Christopher Hogwood" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14ALBUM_ARTIST_SORT" value="Bach, Johann Sebastian; Academy of Ancient Music; Hogwood, Christopher" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14ALBUM_ARTISTS" value="Johann Sebastian Bach;;;Academy of Ancient Music;;;Christopher Hogwood" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="14ALBUM_ARTISTS_SORT" value="Bach, Johann Sebastian;;;Academy of Ancient Music;;;Hogwood, Christopher" class="mediuminputfield" type="text">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the idea but that would just adjust one textarea, maybe my example doesnt make it clear table will contain  a number of rows (typically 20) therefore user wants to expand width of one column, i.e one field on each row not just one field.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my answer to take into account columns of rows. It would be nice if your example contained more than 1 row.

Comment: Actually works quite nicely, although as you say the resized text area not quite same size as the others in column

Comment: I went with other solution since I didnt want to use mutliline text areas, however it has an issue that yours does not it is not allowing me to extend columns widths so wider than screen but your solution does, do you know how I can fix the other solution to allow table to be wider than screen ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. To allow the table to expand beyond the screen width, place it inside a div and set overflow: auto css for that div.

Define the table contents inside 'headers' and 'rows'.

```js
//define table
const headers = [{name:'#', type:'label'}, {name:'Album', type:'input'}, {name:'Genre', type:'input'}, {name:'...', type:'input'}];
const cols = headers.length;
const rows = [
  ['1', 'The Orchestral Suites', 'Johann Sebastian Bach; Academy of Ancient Music, Christopher Hogwood', '...'],
  ['2', 'The Orchestral Suites', 'Johann Sebastian Bach; Academy of Ancient Music, Christopher Hogwood', '...']
];
//create table
const elHeaderRow = document.getElementById('headers');
const elTable = document.getElementById('table');
const allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");//for cursor
//create headers
headers.forEach(({name, type})=>{
  const el = document.createElement('th');
  el.textContent = name;
  elHeaderRow.appendChild(el);
});
let cells = [];
//create rows
rows.forEach((row, rowID)=>{
  const elRow = document.createElement('tr');
  elRow.id = 'row-'+(rowID+1);
  cells.push(...row.map((name, colID)=>{
    const elCell = document.createElement('td');
    const type = headers[colID].type;
    const elRowContents = document.createElement(type);
    if(type === 'input'){
      elRowContents.value = name;
      elRowContents.type = 'text';
    } else {
      elRowContents.textContent = name;
    }
    elCell.appendChild(elRowContents);
    elRow.appendChild(elCell);
    return {rowID:rowID, colID:colID, element: elCell};
  }));
  elTable.appendChild(elRow);
});
const container = document.getElementById('table-container');
//get positions of cells (x etc.)
function getColumnPositions(cells){
  const positions = cells.map(cell=>{
    const rect = cell.element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {x:rect.x, width:rect.width, right: rect.right, element: cell.element};
  });
  return positions;
}
let cellPositions = getColumnPositions(cells);
const dividerWidth = 4;
let cellHit = null;
let isDown = false;
let isResizing = false;
// on mouse move
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  const x = e.pageX;
  const y = e.pageY;
  let tag = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  let bStickRight = false;
  if(tag){
    tag = tag.tagName;
  }
  const insideTable = (tag === "DIV" || tag === "BODY" || tag === "TABLE" || tag === "TD" || tag === "TH" || tag === "INPUT");
  if(insideTable){
    if(!cellHit){
       isResizing = false;
    }
    if(cellHit && isResizing){
      if(container.scrollLeft === container.scrollWidth-container.clientWidth){
      bStickRight = true;
        
        container.scrollLeft = container.scrollWidth;
      }
      cellHit.element.style.width = (x-cellHit.x)+'px';
      cellHit.element.style.minWidth = (x-cellHit.x)+'px';
      if(bStickRight){
        container.scrollLeft = container.scrollWidth;
      }
    } else {
      cellHit = null;
      cellPositions.forEach(cell=>{
        if(Math.abs(x-cell.right) < dividerWidth){
          cellHit = cell;
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
    cellHit = null;
  }
  if(cellHit){
    Array.from(allElements).forEach((el)=>{
      el.style.cursor = 'ew-resize';
      el.style.userSelect = 'none';
    });
  } else {
    Array.from(allElements).forEach((el)=>{
      el.style.cursor = '';
      el.style.userSelect = '';
    });
  }
}, false);
//on mouse down
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
  isDown = true;
  if(cellHit){
    isResizing = true;
  }
}, false);
//on mouse up
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
  isDown = false;
  isResizing = false;
  cellPositions = getColumnPositions(cells);
  Array.from(allElements).forEach((el)=>{
    el.style.cursor = '';
    el.style.userSelect = '';
  });
}, false);
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  min-width: 100%;
}
#table-container {
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 85%;
}
td {
  padding: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table-container">
  <table id="table">
    <tr id="headers">
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```