# Allow html table to resize without hardcoding size greater than page width

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have some Javascript code to allow resizing of table columns, the trouble is that if I make a column wider and the table is already using 100% of the page it will achieve column widening by making other columns smaller.

https://jsfiddle.net/paultaylor/v12x963o/22/

What I want it to do is just make that column wider and leave the other columns the same, this would usually mean that a horzontal scroll bar would then be required and that is fine.

But the only way I seem able to do is by setting table width wider than screensize at start i.e setting table style to width:2000px

But this means the scrollbar is there from start, by default I want table to fit on screen and only be wider than screen if user resizes, also what would I set table width to since 2000px is an arbitary value.

I tried making table style `display: flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;`
but it had no effect

**Note**
The proposed duplicate question was asking for a way to resize table columns, this question uses that solution but asks a specific question about how to allow table width to be greater than screen width in order to allow making a column larger without another being made smaller to compensate

Comment: want something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/v12x963o/26/

Comment: @IsmailFarooq it doesnt seem to solve problem, as I make column wider other columsn are still getting smaller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can user adjust html table column widths during session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49241537/how-can-user-adjust-html-table-column-widths-during-session)

Comment: @Noface no that was my original question, and I was given answer but it doesnt address the specific question of allowing table to go wider

Comment: `table-layout:fixed` might solve ur problem ?

Comment: answers in that question show how to make the table go larger than the page width

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49290316/5674976

Comment: I'd recommend trying setting the parent div of the table to have `width:100%;overflow-x:scroll` and the table to have `min-width:100%;width:auto;` Then the table will grow past 100% but the parent div will scroll

Comment: "To allow the table to expand beyond the screen width, place it inside a div and set overflow: auto css for that div."

Comment: @Noface but your solution did not make the whole screen wider it I found it confusing, also it was for a different approach, I didnt want to use that code as it seemed uncessarily comlex also I tried applying it to the solution I am using and didn't work for me.

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Ive tried that but hasnt worked https://jsfiddle.net/paultaylor/ucgasv5g/5/

Comment: using table is probably complexifying this, use flexbox or something else.

Comment: @Noface the table represents multi row tabular data that the user can enter, I cant see how using Flexbox instead of  table is going to work.  Maybe using Grid Layout would work but these layaouts are all new to me so table seemed a good fit and I dont feel Im asking anything particularly new here.

Comment: it is semantically nicer but technically harder to work with because of the way you have a tr (rows) as the immediate children of the table which makes setting css for the cells a bit harder. check out https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/

Comment: if you need anything more than a simple table and it is overly complex, as we can see in your case where you are customizing the table column widths based on user input.

Comment: @Noface are your last comments referring to table, flexbox or grid layout ?

Comment: the `table` element

Comment: When I have more time I will take some time to learn grid-layout but for now I will just have to stick with what I have got, suprised this question is no difficult to get a correct answer for though

Comment: just organize the html into columns instead of rows, then resizing columns should be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Without table element it is simpler to let the elements overflow beyond the page width.

I suggest defining your table data in JSON and then generating the html programatically from this data.

This code is just to overflow beyond page width.

```js
const cols = getCols(4);//array of the col-n elements
function getCols(nCols){
  const arr = [];
  for(let i=0;i<nCols;i++){
    arr.push(document.getElementById(`col-${i}`));
  }
  return arr;
}
//use custom code on cols as you already have to change their widths.
//probably better to ignore the left side of the first column and the right side of the last column.
//decide how to handle the right column width considering you cannot drag beyond the page width.
/*
e.g.
on drag check mouse x distance to element.right, if within range (e.g. 8 px), set element.width to distance of element.left from mouse x.
*/
```

```css
#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
.col {
  display: inline-block;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 30ch;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- this should be generated with javascript with the table data as a JSON object -->
<div id="container">
  <div id="col-0" class="col">
    <div id="header-0"> Header 0 </div>
    <input id="input-0-0" value="input 0.0" type="text">
    <input id="input-0-1" value="input 0.1" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="col-1" class="col">
    <div id="header-1"> Header 1 </div>
    <input id="input-1-0" value="input 1.0" type="text">
    <input id="input-1-1" value="input 1.1" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="col-2" class="col">
    <div id="header-2"> Header 2 </div>
    <input id="input-2-0" value="input 2.0" type="text">
    <input id="input-2-1" value="input 2.1" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="col-3" class="col">
    <div id="header-3"> Header 3 </div>
    <input id="input-3-0" value="input 3.0" type="text">
    <input id="input-3-1" value="input 3.1" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My code is already generated programmatically, but on server side rather than client. I don't see how your solution solves my issue since the columns are not being resized in your answer the table is already wider than screen to start with. But if you can fix my jsfiddle so that it does allow table to be wider than screen when user widens columns then I would be grateful and award you a bounty.